# How to convert Byte[] formated image to Base64string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display an image from sql db  to my web page,
I got the image in the format
**{byte[6317]}** 
How to convert it into **Base64string**.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript Approach with Base64.js library

Since u specified that u want to convert it using JavaScript you can do it with the Base64 JavaScript library. It has the following methods:

> toByteArray - Takes a base64 string and returns a byte array

And

> fromByteArray - Takes a byte array and returns a base64 string

Here is an example how you could do it. First, return from ASP.NET MVC a response like this:

```
return Json(new { Img = imageBytes }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And then on the client you can use jQuery getJson() function to get the JSON response from the MVC ImageController:

```
$.getJSON("/Image",function(result){
   $.each(result, function(i, field){
     var byteArray = result.Img;

     var base64 = base64js.fromByteArray(byteArray);

     $("#mainimg").attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64);
   });
});
```

You can download the base64.js library from here:

https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js

### C# Convert approach

If you don't like the base64 javascript approach you could convert the byte array on the server with C# using:

```
String base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
return Json(new { Img = base64string }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This would return the Base64 string in the JSON Result. Then you can easily set your img source from jQuery as displayed in the Javascript Approach example.

Comment: Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("path");
String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("path");
String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

And correspondingly, read back to file:

Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64Str);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This Code,

```
 byte[] imgBytes = (byte[])yourbytedata;
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length);
    string htmlstr = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

Comment: Question is about javascript

Comment: Ok so try btoa convertsion.